# Convert int to class pointer?

Tags: c++, casting, user-defined-types

I am trying to create a cast from `A*` to int where `A` is a class I've defined.

The conversion is from a lookup, (the int is the id of that A instance) in case you wanted to know.

Currently, I have:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A{
  private:
    int val;
  public:

    A(){};
    A(int val): val(val){};
    
    static A* cast(int val){
      return &(A());
      //This will actually be a valid pointer 
    }
  
    explicit operator int(){
      return val;
    }
};

int main() {
  A a(7);
  
  std::cout << "Pointer: " << &a << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Pointer cast: " << A::cast(5) << std::endl; //would like this to be static_cast<A*>(5)
  std::cout << "Int cast: " << static_cast<int>(a) << std::endl;
}
```

I can create a nice cast from `A` to `int`. However, I cannot figure out how to define the casts for `A*` to `int` and vice versa.

Note: I currently have this working as a function in the `A` class, but a cast-style conversion would feel more natural in my use case.

Comment: `return &(A());` Your're returning the address of a ravlue. Do you really expect that?

Comment: What is your use case? Because none of this looks natural.

Comment: Are you looking for [std::map<int, A>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)?

Comment: @Nimrod, only for the example. That’s why I put the comment there. I’m surprised, though it compiled and ran without issues

Comment: @FantasticMrFox What specifically? Rather than having a function ’A::to_int(A*)’ I would like to be able to do ‘static_cast<int>(A*)’ by defining the conversion.

Comment: @BoP, no I already have a similar implementation using a vector. What I’m looking for is the way to retrieve the item both ways. Sure this would let me do map_name[5], but not the other way around.I would prefer casting 5 to A* using my own defined conversion

Comment: But `A*` is a pointer to A...? You can always cast this to an int, but it is probably not what you want. Surely using a function of a like `A a; a->as_int()` makes more sense and is nicer ...